# 3d tensor multiplication

Tags: tensors

I'm new to tensor theory, and I have a question.

It's easy to know how to multiply a $2d$ tensor with another $2d$ tensor: $$A_{ij} \times B_{jk} = C_{ik}$$
However, can I multiply a $3d$ tensor with another $3d$ tensor?
If yes, please tell me how or give me a reference reading.

Thank you so much.

Comment: I honestly do not understand what exacly you mean by that "multiplication" of 2d tensors.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez I'm sure he means matrix multiplication.

Comment: @FireGarden, that would require a sum somewhere.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez It is a common convention for repeated indices to imply a summation over those indices.

Comment: I am perfectly aware of that, but I am almost sure that most of the readers of the question are not...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A $k$-dimensional tensor can loosely be defined as a $k$-dimensional array of numbers $(a_{i_1\cdots i_k})_{1\leq i_1,\ldots,i_k\leq n}$ which behaves "appropriately" under coordinate changes. The example from your question ($A_{ij} \times B_{jk} = C_{ik}$) is a so-called *contraction* of tensors, i.e. we sum over one index of each so that only the other indices remain. Another kind of multiplication is $A_{ij} \cdot B_{pq} =: D_{ijpq},$ i.e. we multiply the $2$-dimensional tensors coordinate-wise so that we get a $4$-dimensional tensor. Actually, this operation is called the *tensor product*. If you have more indices, it works completely analogous. For example, we can contract a $3$D tensor and a $4$D tensor to a $((3-1)+(4-1) = 5)$D tensor:
$$
\sum_{j=1}^n X_{ijk}Y_{abjc} = Z_{ikabc}.
$$
Of course, you can "contract" using other pairs of indices.

For reading, you can start here:
[Tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor),
[Contraction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction),
[Multilinear algebra](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_algebra#Topics_in_multilinear_algebra),
[Einstein summation convention](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation),
[Mixed tensor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mixed_tensor),
[Multilinear map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilinear_map).

Comment: Thank you so much! I was thinking of how to contract a 3D tensor with another 3D tensor to the other 3D tensor. Now I know it's impossible.